# Does the following query limit SQL Select

Tags: sql, select

I have an events log database. I need to limit the size of SQL searches when looking for a specific `EventID`. This is for performance purpose.

Does the following query limits the SQL Query?

```
SELECT EventID FROM
    (SELECT TOP 100000 EventID,EventName FROM Events ORDER BY EventTime DESC) T
WHERE EventName = 'Whatever'
```

Rather than doing the following

```
SELECT EventID FROM Events WHERE EventName = 'Whatever'
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "limit" the SQL Query?

Comment: He prob. wants to know if the subquery is limited by the where clause. It is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query 1 will locate top 100.000 events by Event time, then filter those records by EventName = 'Whatever' - the result will be <= 100.000 events.

Query 2 will locate all events where EventName = 'Whatever'

I can only guess you're trying to achieve the following:

```
SELECT TOP 100000 EventID 
FROM Events 
WHERE EventName = 'Whatever'
ORDER BY EventTime DESC) T
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the top one will only return the most recent (ordered by Event Time) 100,000 records. If you wanted the EventID for all records and there were more than 100,000, you results wouldn't include them all. It'd be a faster query though than selecting them all.

Comment: Providing you have over 100,000 rows in that table yes :). It's better rewritten into SELECT TOP 100000 EventID, EventName FROM Events WHERE EventName = 'Whatever' ORDER BY EventTime DESC